# Is it possible to animate scroll using jquery without $('html, body')?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I need `<body>` and `<html>` on my page always have `ovreflow:hidden`. Child overall wrapper `#main-wrapper` has `overflow-y: scroll` and i try to make animation on it. But unfortunately `$('#my_element').offset().top` is always different. Its value depends on where my viewport is.

Look at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nevcn3vo/11/) please

Comment: animateContainer = $('#main-wrapper');  from the jsfiddle hope it will do as you want

Comment: @Akshaypadwal, nope... You can check it by scrolling #main-wrapper until "click me" button and then click it. You will see that scroll will animate incorrect, not until section#block

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary to add on more children element of `#main-wrapper`, wrapped the whole content. I added `<div>` and it started work properly. Look at the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/nevcn3vo/11/).